# SQL Program a column to automaticly make a calcul

Tags: mysql, unity-game-engine, calculated-columns

I'm making an Unity game (connected to my website), when the player finish a level unity send name, score, time, date , and add 1 to the win or 1 to the defeat.

I want my column ratio to automaticly make a calcul : "win column" / "loose column".

I'm new to php and I didn't found any answer to my question. The only thing that I'm not able to do is to set an automatic calculation on my column, I searched if I can found an option like this on phpmyadmin but I didn't found it.

Thx for your help and sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Could you please post what code you've tried so far? It's good to post what you've tried so far on StackOverflow, so that other readers can take a look and help point you in the right direction. Cheers :)

Comment: I haven't try any code because I don't want to use code, I want to set an option wich calculate automaticly if it possible